# How to add row in google sheet synchronously?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, google-apps-script, google-sheets, async-await

I'm using google-spreadsheet library to access and insert data to Google Sheets. I was able to add multiple rows but each row is being added in no particular order, I guess due to the addRow() async behavior.

Example data is:

```
let myData = [{id: "1", fname: "John"}, {id: "2", fname: "Matt"}, {id: "3", fname: "Paul"}]

for (let i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    let row = myData[i];

    // Async call to insert row.
    doc.addRow(sheetIndex, row, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;    
    });
}
```

For-loop iterates and passes each row object to addRow() but it doesn't care what the order is when each row gets inserted to Googlesheets.

I've tried doing an async-await approach to wait for doc.addRow() before it iterates to next  row object but I have no luck. Is there a way to achieve the insertion in the same order I pass it? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You are calling method with callback inside loop. So, it will start execution but will not wait for complete the operation. You can use promise version if available for same. Otherwise new Promise(( res, rej )=>{ //code resolve from callback})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't await the function probably because it does't return Promise. So, lets promisify that function first.

```
function asyncAddRow(sheetIndex, row) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    doc.addRow(sheetIndex, row, (err) => {
      if (err) rej(err);
      else res(true);
    });
  })
}
```

Now, instead of calling `doc.addRow` you call our `asyncAddRow`. Since it returns a promise so you can await it now. Like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
  let row = myData[i];

  await asyncAddRow(sheetIndex, row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `append()`

```
let values = [
  [
    // Cell values ...
  ],
  // Additional rows ...
];
let resource = {
  values,
};
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.append({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
  valueInputOption,
  resource,
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error.
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(`${result.updates.updatedCells} cells appended.`);
  }
});
```

[More info there](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values)